# MVC XML Model as Property on another Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have a model with this property:

```
[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "xml")]
public string Data { get; set; }
```

And a Model to represent that data:

```
[XmlRoot("data")]
public class Data
{
    [Required]
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [XmlElement("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to bind that property to the data model? I'd like to take advantage of MVC form controls such as:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

Is this possible somehow or am I going to have to manually serialise/deserialse the XML and build my own form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that instead of declaring `public string Data { get; set; }` on the first model you need to declare `public Data Data { get; set; }` to make EditorFor render the custom model.

But yes, you'll need to deserialize and create a custom .cshtml editor or view template to display the data.